# How to remove line feed in text file created via Batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have batch file whose job is to create a text file and write the content

```
REM CreateFile.bat
@echo off
echo %1> C:\temp\%1.txt
exit
```

Ex: If I call the `CreateFile.bat DB12232131` this going to create a text file `DB12232131.txt` with content `DB12232131`

But the text file created has a line feed

```
    DB12232131
```

How can i remove the Line feed?

Thanks

Karthik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `echo` always append a linefeed you can use a workaround.

```
<nul set /p ".=%1" > c:\temp\%1.txt
```

But `set/p` have some limitations, like removing leading spaces and tabs and fail with leading equal signs, but I suppose it can be igrnored in your case.

Comment: Works great. Thanks a lot. what does <nul do?

Comment: `set /p` is inteded for waiting for user input, but with `<nul` the user input is empty and it doesn't wait, it only echo's the "user prompt"